# Is it possible to alter javascript with google closure compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm working on a modular component framework and have different needs for the code in my test environment vs production.  Each component has its own js file and these are being compiled together for production use, but left separate in my dev environment.

In production I want to trap errors in various stages of initialization so as to not break the call stack.  In my development (uncompressed javascript), I do not want to trap the errors, so I can quickly get line numbers, etc to find where the breaks occur.  Is there any way to use the closure compiler to manipulate a javascript file (such as removing a flagged line such as a comment opener and closer) that might allow me to do this?

For instance:

```
proto.instantiateChildFromDescriptor = function(childObj, callback, customDiv){
/*ProductionErrorTrap
    try{
/**/
    //code for instantiating a module
/*ProductionErrorTrap
    }catch(e){
        console.log("problem instantiating child in " + this.getName());
        console.error(e);
    }
/**/
}
```

replacing `/*ProductionErrorTrap` with `/*ProductionErrorTrap*/`  would work nicely  (so is removing my stars on the second comment block, but they are there)

I can't do this with a find and replace on the files themselves because it would mess with github.   I suppose I could create a new copy of the files, run a find and replace on them and compile *those files, but It would be nice if I could do it all in the closure compiler.

Thanks

Comment: So you basically are looking for an ifDef, right?

Comment: Looks like it (had to look that up in this context) so I'm a little fuzzy on how to / if I can implement that here.

Comment: on second thought, I don't think that will work...  The reason being is that I'm creating try catch statements that won't work in that way because they manipulate code blocks.

Comment: For performance reasons, you'll want to use your comment trick because you don't want those code in there (even if it is skipped by an if-statement etc.)  I assume you're going for performance (otherwise why use Closure?)  Mark your comments with `@preserve` so that they'll survive in Advanced mode.  They'll translate through to the compiled code.  When error comes, you just have to modify the compiled file; you never need to mess with the source files or recompile.  However, the pitfalls is that your code download will be bloated with all these comments.

Comment: If you are worried about code bloat for the download, or breaking your obfuscation, then just put in an error code (and you keep your error-code-to-error-description mapping table).  Understand that you'll need to **rethrow** your exception after you logged it, otherwise your error reporting will change your code's behavior.

Comment: @preserve... sounds like what I'm needing.  I'll try that, thanks.  Would you mind pasting that in the answers section?

Comment: You don't have to do anything as complicated as modifying compiled code. Just code normally using if statements and functions. Unnecessary code will be eliminated in the result, trust the compiler. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think messing with compiled results, matching comments to emulate ifdefs is pretty unelegant.

You could actually do something like this:

```
debugTry(function() {
    alert('This is code that might cause an error');
},function(e) {
    alert('Whoops! Caught error '+e);
});
```

Then while debugging you do:

```
function debugTry(test,handle) {
    try {
        test();
    } catch(e) {
        handle(e);
    }
}
```

And in production:

```
function debugTry(test,handle) {
    test();
}
```

Closure Compiler is pretty smart. With the first debugTry the example compiles to:

```
try{alert("This is code that might cause an error")}
catch(a){alert("Whoops! Caught error "+a)};
```

With the second debugTry it compiles to:

```
alert("This is code that might cause an error");
```

As you see, the unnecessary code is detected and eliminated.

Of course, things would be easier if you didn't conditionally include a try block. If it's just some statements included conditionally, not changing the structure of other code, you can do:

```
/** @const */ var debug = false;

if(debug) {
    alert('Yay for debugging!');
}
```

The alert will be compiled away.

Comment: Brilliant, this will tie into centralized error reporting pretty well in our phonegap apps as well.

Comment: I'm thinking about something similar like:
    if(debug){
       tryFunction = debugTry:
    }else{
       tryFunction = justDoIt;
    }
Where those two functions map to the two versions of debugTry you mentioned above.  I'll report back if that works well for us.

Answer (score 1):

Use compiler flags for advanced mode.

from:
https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler

```
@define {Type} description
```

For example:

```
/** @define {boolean} */
var ENABLE_DEBUG = true;

/** @define {boolean} */
goog.userAgent.ASSUME_IE = false;
```

Indicates a constant that can be overridden by the compiler at compile-time. With the example above, you can pass the flag `--define='ENABLE_DEBUG=false'` to the compiler to change the value of `ENABLE_DEBUG` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Chung's comment seems to be the best approach.  Adding his comments as an answer to this question for anyone else with this problem.  I entered the following into my code

```
 proto.updateProperties = function(propsObj){
 /** @preserve ProductionErrorTrap try{ /**/
    //do stuff here
 /** @preserve ProductionErrorTrap }catch(e){console.log("problem updating properties in " + this.getName());console.error(e);}/**/
 }
```

After compressing the javascript I just run a find and replace on the compressed file, remove the line breaks and replace ProductionErrorTrap with ProductionErrorTrap*/ and everything seems to work fine without making a mess of the repository.

Thanks Stephen!

Comment: By the way, those line breaks are there for a reason. [Closure Compiler FAQ: Why are there random line feeds in compiled scripts?](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/faq#linefeeds)